Safari iOS mobile issue with swiper
Im having issues with initializing swiper on Safari mobile iOS. It works perfectly fine on any other browser or device.
Looks like DOMContentLoaded is not working properly here:
<script>
    'use strict';
    (() => {
        const initSwipers = (allModuleBanners) => {

            const prepareSingleSwiper = (singleBanner) => {
                const sliderConfig = singleBanner.dataset.bannerconfig;
                const configJson = JSON.parse(sliderConfig);

                const sliderForBanner = singleBanner.querySelector('.swiper');
                const sliderPagination = sliderForBanner.querySelector('.swiper-pagination');
                const sliderNavigationPrev = sliderForBanner.querySelector('.swiper-button-prev');
                const sliderNavigationNext = sliderForBanner.querySelector('.swiper-button-next');

                const baseConfig = {
                    slidesPerView: configJson.slidesPerView,
                    loop: configJson.loop,
                    speed: configJson.speed,
                    effect: configJson.effect
                }

                const finalConfig = Object.assign({}, baseConfig);

                if (configJson.autoplay && configJson.autoplay.delay) {
                    const autoplayElement = {
                        delay: configJson.autoplay.delay,
                        pauseOnMouseEnter: configJson.autoplay.pauseOnMouseEnter
                    }

                    finalConfig['autoplay'] = autoplayElement;
                }

                if (configJson.navigation) {
                    const navigationElement = {
                        nextEl: sliderNavigationNext,
                        prevEl: sliderNavigationPrev,
                    }

                    finalConfig['navigation'] = navigationElement;
                }

                if (configJson.pagination) {
                    const paginationElement = {
                        el: sliderPagination,
                        type: 'bullets',
                        clickable: true
                    }

                    finalConfig['pagination'] = paginationElement;
                }

                const swiper = new Swiper(sliderForBanner, finalConfig);

            };

            allModuleBanners.forEach(singleBanner => {
                const swiperAlreadyExist = singleBanner.querySelector('.swiper').swiper;
                if (!swiperAlreadyExist) {
                    prepareSingleSwiper(singleBanner);
                }
            });
        };

        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            const allModuleBanners = document.querySelectorAll('.banner-full-one-wrapper .swiper-banner');
            if (allModuleBanners.length > 0) {
                if (window.Swiper) {
                    initSwipers(allModuleBanners);
                }
            }
        });
    })();
</script>

I saw this workaround in here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651215 but it doesn't seem to work for me or I'm not executing it well.
